# Fill in dropdown after a different dropdown gets selected

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to come up with a way that would automatically populate a drop down based on the value selected in a different drop down.

Lets say I have a drop down for State / Province. Depending which value gets selected it would fill in the Country drop down to be USA / CAN.

```
<select name="formState" class="form-control modeldropdown" id="state" required>
    <option value="">State / Province</option>
    <option value="">--- United States  ---</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama - AL</option>
    ...
    <option value="MH">Marshall Islands - MH</option>
    <option value="">--- Canada ---</option>
    <option value="AB">Alberta - AB</option>
    <option value="BC">British Columbia - BC</option>
    ...
</select>
```

It would be easier to do it the reversed way (select a country then it filters) -- for that I would do something like this

```
   var jsonText = '{"USA":{ '
        + '"Alabama": "Alabama",'
        + '"Alaska": "Alaska",'
        + '},'
        + '"CAN":{'
        + '"Alberta": "Alberta",'
        + '}}';
    var json = JSON.parse(jsonText);
```

And then filter it based on which Country was selected, but is there an easy way to do the reversed?

The only way I can think to do this is by checking the value to see if it is:

```
var state = $('#state').val();

if ( state == 'Alabama' || state == 'Alaska'...)
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an object that maps from state/province to country:

```
const countryOfState = {
  'Alabama' : 'USA',
  'Alberta' : 'CAN'
};

let state = $('#state').val();

if (countryOfState[state] === 'USA') {
...
```

Comment: I was thinking about that but then wasnt too happy with all the reused code in the json (ie: USA used 50 times)

Comment: I've posted an alternate solution that avoids duplicating the countries

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexOf` to check if an element exists in an array like so:

```
const states = {
  'USA': ['Alabama'],
  'CAN': ['Alberta']
};

function getCountry(state) {
  for (let country in states) {
    if (states[country].indexOf(state) >= 0) {
      return country;
    }
  }

  return null;
}

console.log(getCountry('Alberta')); //CAN
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly sideways approach using `optgroup` which I think works better for your data anyway. I've also utilised [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

```js
$('#state').change(function() {
  var optGroup = $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).closest('optgroup');
  var label = $(optGroup).prop('label');
  var cCode = $(optGroup).data('countrycode');
  $('#country').html('<option value="'+ cCode  + '">' + label + '</option>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="formState" class="form-control modeldropdown" id="state" required>
    <option value="">State / Province</option>
    <optgroup label="United States" data-countryCode="USA">
       <option value="AL">Alabama - AL</option>
       <!-- ... -->
       <option value="MH">Marshall Islands - MH</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Canada" data-countryCode="CA">
       <option value="AB">Alberta - AB</option>
       <option value="BC">British Columbia - BC</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<select id="country" name="country"><option disabled selected>Please Select State</option></select>
```